# responsive navigation - change limit for switch between classic nav and dropdown nav

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I am beginner with using responsive design and I have big problem. I need to change limit for switch between clastic nav and dropdown nav. Current limit is `600px`, but I need to change it for example to 800. I am using this navigation: http://media02.hongkiat.com/responsive-web-nav/demo/index.html
Can somebody help me?

Comment: Post some CSS/HTML so we know what you are talking about.

Comment: add @media screen and (max-width: 800px) { *{background-color:red;} } to your style.css and see what happens

Answer (score 1):

in your stylesheet, change `@media screen and (max-width: 600px)` to `@media screen and (max-width: 800px)`

Comment: I am sorry it look like that I described my problem bad. I need to change limit between switching from clasic navigation between dropdown navigation, that happens on 460px : http://postimg.org/image/42563rbcl/ I am pretty sure, that this is not problem of css, because this resize works (looks horrible but works) even if I delete all @media commands in my css. Sorry for my  bad english I hope, that you will understand

Comment: Then you need to change `@media only screen and (max-width : 480px)` to something larger.

The code that makes your dropdown visible is in that media query. 
`nav a#pull {
display: block;
background-color: #283744;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
}`